# How can I read the log when I fail with VPN

Tags: vpn

I have a Macbook Pro and I'm trying to get VPN from home to work. It refuse to work. I have turned on verbose logging, but how can I read the log ?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Whether you choose L2TP over IPSec or PPTP for your settings, the log file is located at:

> /var/log/ppp.log

If you want use terminal to view your log file you can do following:

> vim /var/log/ppp.log
>
> tail -f /var/log/ppp.log       (if you
>   want see end of file)
>
> less /var/log/ppp.log  (if your log
>   file was huge and want to see page by
>   page)

Comment: For additional information on IPSec, use the built-in "syslog" command to query all logs for messages from the racoon key management daemon:


    syslog -k Facility -k Sender racoon

Comment: This answer no longer seems relevant: on OS X El Capitan, there is no /var/log/ppp.log.  There is a /var/log/ppp/ directory, but it's empty.  Logs seem to go into /var/log/system.log.

Comment: @D.W. I'm on Sierra 10.12.6 and /var/log/ppp.log is still being written to as I write

Comment: Where can I find Cisco IPSec logs?

Comment: Not using the terminal and just to extend previous information, on mac open the Console Tool and on the right side (explorer) and click on /var/log you should see in the middle panel a list of logs, click on the ppp.log

Comment: On Mojave, this file does not exist, even after enabling verbose logging for L2TP

Answer (score 20):

For completeness, I'll add a way to view the log in the GUI.

Open the Console utility, select Show Log List from the toolbar (if it isn't already shown), then select FILES > /private/var/log > ppp.log from the sidebar.

On macOS Catalina, the toolbar reads "Log Reports", then ppp.log

[image: The macOS Console application on macOS Catalina]

Answer (score 3):

MacOS 14.x -> None of the above is relevant.

- `/var/log/ppp.log` does not exist
- `/var/log/ppp` is empty
- `/var/log/system.log` only prints the process ID on VPN connect, but no additional info when it fails, fails during connecting (assuming some handshake did not complete etc.)

*Example from system.log when connecting to VPN:*

```
login[6631]: USER_PROCESS: 6631 ttys003
```